# PowerShell Tee-Object command with -Append

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I run into an issue with the PowerShell 4.0 [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Tee-Object?view=powershell-5.1) command (alias `tee`) and the command that I'm using is as follows:

```
powershell "cmd /c dir | Tee-Object -filepath C:\1.txt -Append"
```

When 1.txt is an empty file, it writes the output as you see on the screen (as-is). But if 1.txt has some existing content before you run the command, it appends the output with no new lines and the files looks completely messed up.

I'm surprised to see this behavior and any thoughts would help me to proceed further. Note that I have to use the Tee-Object command as I would like to see the output on the screen when a command is running and append it to the existing log file that has some contents.

Comment: Running your exact commands I don't see any issue, 1.txt looks fine even after running multiple times.  Question for you, why mix DOS and powershell?  Might have more consistant results when working with cmdlets.  `gci | tee -filepath 1.txt -Append`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I actually use this in one of my build step ( windows command) in Jenkins. cmd /c dir - picked up as an example...I actually call a perl script in it's place...Several previous steps in the job writes the output to the same file and when it comes to this powershell tee command it, it writes the output;but messes with up encoding.... If you try the command that i shared from dos command prmopt, you would see the same result that i see...

Comment: Strange, ran it several times and `1.txt` on my system seems fine, no encoding/line break issues.

Comment: Oops...I did not explain it right :-( Thanks for your time and support. This is what i exactly tried and i see an issue with the encoding that the powershell tee command uses... i tried the following commands in the order: 1. ECHO Line 1 >C:\1.txt 2. ECHO Line 2 >>C:\1.txt 3. ECHO Line 3 >>C:\1.txt 4.powershell "cmd /c dir | tee -filepath c:\1.txt -Append"

Comment: Matt, I think, you see my issue now...

Answer (score 0):

Note that Tee-Object write with UTF16LE encoding, that is why!

Answer (score 0):

Like out-file -append or ">>", tee-object -append can destructively mix different encodings in the same file, and default to utf16, even if the file already has ascii characters.

```
echo hi1 | set-content file
echo hi2 | tee-object -FilePath file -append

(get-content file) -replace '\0','\0'  # show extra nulls from utf16

hi1
h\0i\02\0
\0
\0
```

Tee to a variable, and use add-content to append to a file instead.  Add-content will check the BOM and match the encoding.

```
echo hi1 | set-content file
echo hi2 | tee-object -variable out
$out | add-content file

(get-content file) -replace '\0','\0'

hi1
hi2
```